Replicaset vs Replicaset Controller Please clarify

Does Replicaset and Replicaset Controller mean the same thing and therefore interchangeable words? Or is there one Replicaset Controller that controls all the replicasets in the cluster and therefore these are two different objects?

When a deployment is created, does it spin up a brand new Replicaset Controller that controls the replicaset created for that specific deployment?



Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64546189/23310241

@helpinghand not quite. So, when a deployment is created, does brand new replicaset controller get spun up supports it's pods/replicas?

Kubernetes controllers are code that form part of the Kubernetes system that monitor (Kubernetes) Resources in the cluster's namespaces and attempt to bring the Resources into a desired state. ReplicaSets are a Kubernetes Resource that are managed by a ReplicaSet Controller.

@jssteele89 no, a brand new replication controller doesn’t get spun up when a deployment is created. The Replication Controller is an Kubernetes component that exists within the kube-controller-manager, and it basically ensures that a specific number of pod replicas are running at any given time.

@helpinghand So a new replicaset is spun with a deployment, yea? and there is a "replicaset controller" that control all the replicasets?
